# DIff ignore arguments from a file doesn't seem to be working

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, diff

When I run the following command, it doesn't seem to be ignoring what I specify in the ignore.txt file. I have tried adding some of the arguments with `-x`, but there are way too many to do that by hand.

This is the command I ran:

```
diff -rcP -X ignore.txt linux-3.10.10 projfolder > submission/patchfile.diff
```

The diff file that is created includes things that were supposed to be ignored.
Does anyone know what may be happening? Am I just using diff incorrectly?

Example of what's in the ignore.txt:

```
*build*
*drivers*
*scripts*
*sound*
.tmp_*
..tmp_*
.config*
*.o
*.ko
*.cmd
*.mod.c
*vmlinux*
.kconf*
```

Comment: Could you include a minimal example? What is in the file? Or are these directories (they should be)? What is supposed to be ignored? What is your output and what should it have been?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the character encoding. For some reason it had carriage return line feeds. I'm not sure why this happened in the first place since none were actually put in the file. But I ran:

```
dos2unix ignore.txt
```

And ran diff again and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Using `diff (GNU diffutils) 3.2` on my system, this makes no difference, either format works correctly.